# Unable to Ssh on another ISP

Tags: ssh, vps

When I ssh to my host vps I am able to connect and login easily when on different ISP's i.e.,

1. My Phone's internet connection
2. My Friends internet connection

But when I do it at my home,
I get response by ping but unable to connect to ssh using either of,

1. dns name
2. ip address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure that the IP you tried to connect to is a public IP.

Second, if you are using a router, make sure that port forwarding from the router to the destination PC is properly configured. You can usually set it on the router's settings page.

If the ping is entered correctly but the connection is denied, it is likely to be a configuration problem on the router. Or, your ISP may have blocked that port, so use the port scan site to make sure that the port is blocked. If you search for port scanner online on Google, you will see many sites.

Comment: thanks, the ISP has blocked that port, I changed the ssh port to 222 and now can happily connect, thanks for your valuable input!